# HtmlAgilityPack convert XPath query to LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, xpath, xamarin

I'm struggeling with converting a XPath query to LINQ...
Using HtmlAgilityPack from NuGet with Xamarin to parse a webpage.
The problem is that I cannot use XPath in Xamarin as it's not supported from the NuGet package, and since I don't have license to compile my own HtmlAgilityPack.dll I have to use LINQ instead.

The following XPath query is what I'm trying to convert to LINQ:

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@id='bodyContent_gridHundar']//tr[descendant::td and not(@class='pagestyle')]")
```

Thanks in advance!

**Updated with correct answer!**

```
doc.DocumentNode.Descendants ("table")
.Where (o => o.GetAttributeValue ("id", "") == "bodyContent_gridHundar")
.First ()
.Descendants ("tr")
.Where (o => o.Descendants ("td").Any () && o.GetAttributeValue ("class", "") != "pagestyle");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way :

```
doc.DocumentNode
   // '//table' :
   .Descendants("table")
   // '[@id='bodyContent_gridHundar']' :
   .Where(o => o.GetAttributeValue("id", "") == "bodyContent_gridHundar")
   // '//tr' :
   .Descendants("tr")
   // '[descendant::td and not(@class='pagestyle')]' :
   .Where(o => o.Descendants("td").Any() && o.GetAttributeValue("class", "") != "pagestyle")
```

Comment: Thank you! Had to add a .First() after the first .Where() function.
Updated my question with this solution!